# Sorting an ArrayList of objects

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, arraylist

I am having some frustration trying to get an ArrayList of a custom object type sorted.  I am trying to use LINQ  and the following code is what I have for a test:

```
        foreach (classOrder co in orderList)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Before: " + co.Feet);
        }

        //use LINQ to sort my orderList which is an ArrayList of classOrder objects
        var sortedList = orderList.OfType<classOrder>().OrderBy(r => r.Feet);

        foreach (classOrder co in sortedList)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("After: " + co.Feet);
        }
```

Obviously this is not correct <strike>because the output from the foreach at the bottom is the same as the top.</strike> because it is only sorting the first digit.  Feet is a string but contains digits.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: of what type is `Feet`

Comment: Shouldn't be the same (unless collection is already sorted). Could you show your data, please?

Comment: I just realized that it was appearing not to work because it was only taking into account the first digit.  Feet is a string but contains digits.  If I had objects with feet of 10, 1, 15 for example, it didn't do anything.  I just tried with 20, 1, 5 and it sorted it but it is sorting as 1, 20, 5... so it appears it is only looking at the first digit because it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

For an arrayList, perhaps you should use sort.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t.aspx

I would recommend avoiding ArrayList if at all possible or unless you need it for a specific purpose.  In this case, List or whatever type you need it to be would be preferable, since it gives you access to fantastic extension methods like OrderBy

Comment: `OfType` is type filter + cast

Comment: @Magnus I went back to the docs and you're correct.  I should have realized this before but most likely the cast is failing since it can't cast to his type.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement IComparable iinterface in your custom class and then you can use simple List.Sort() function.